# How to use Hashmap with Adapter

Tags: android, listview, drawable

Hello I am parsing some json on android and I have been able to put the json parsed data into a listview. However on my listview, I also have some icons that I would like to set the status according to the parsed data ( I have some keys that define their status, 1 for enabled and 0 for disabled). I can't seem to put this on the HashMap, anyone has any tip/information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HashMap<String,Boolean> map = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();

Collection c = map.values();

Iterator itr = c.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext())
     System.out.println(itr.next());
}
```

Comment: but how can I use this to change the boolean of drawable.set_enabled? i already tried HashMap<String,Boolean>

Comment: Yes, it works, I am now getting those values on the task. But the information is not being updated for the icons, only for the text (I used

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DisponiveisActivity.this, disponiveislist, R.layout.listrow,new String[]{"NOME","PRECO","DISTANCIA","COMFOTOGRAFIA","COMDESLOCACAO"}, new int[]{R.id.mission_name, R.id.preco, R.id.distancia}); .when i add icons to this line they wont update. how can i reference the selector state, and map the value to it? 

Thank you very much